# alter alert dialog on window close

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

If the user tries to close the window the alert pops up and I want to change the text so a user has the option to leave the page or can choose to stay and redirect to another page.

Probably searching for it in the wrong way but I really can't find anything that works.

What I have so far:

`window.onbeforeunload = function() { /*...*/ }`

I need to know how to adjust the text of the alert and add a handler on the stay button.

Comment: You can no more use custom message on most modern browsers due to abuse. They all tend to now use FF behaviour where custom message was disabled from long time ago

Comment: Sounds like you need a WinForms application...

Comment: @user3398922 check my answer in the duplication question above. It covers all your options.

Comment: That was really a duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

For altering the text I dont know exactly how to help you, but you could use the `confirm()` function from the `window` object.

This would look like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var answer;
  var result = confirm("Press a button!");
  if (result === true) {
      answer = "You pressed OK!";
  }   else {
      answer = "You pressed Cancel!";
  }
  alert(answer);
}
```

Refer to [this post](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp).

UPDATE: `onbeforeunload` blocks the dialog. A much simpler solution would be to return something from the event, then you'd get asked in any case:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return "";
};
//Are you sure you want to leave?
```

Comment: `You could fire the confirmation alert in the onbeforeunload event` No, this is disabled from beforeunload handler

Comment: @A.Wolff true, you have to `return`.